# angular 2 component get style value

Tags: javascript, angular

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'box',
    templateUrl: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
    host : {
        //"(style.width:change)" : "width"
    }
})
export class ComponentNameComponent implements OnInit {
    private width : number;
    private element : HTMLElement;
    constructor(element: ElementRef) {
        this.element = element.nativeElement;
        this.width = this.element.offsetWidth;
    }

    ngOnInit() { }

}
```

is there a more effective way to get the width of a given element without using the ElementRef? I feel angular 2 doesn't want you to direct access to the dom because of the renderer. I wish i could write something like  "(style.width.px:change)" : "setWidth($value)" or similar. Maybe I'm missing something can anyone give some insight here?

Comment: There is the `Ruler` class that can be used for that purpose.

Comment: This is not a valid solution. Please see https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8452 Ruler has been removed as of RC0

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had a hunch there was such an issue (I'm just back from vacation). This means some reorg caused the missing export but it should be back again with one of the next updates. Therefore I'd keep your workaround until `Ruler` is again available or you import it from `src/` as a workaround until the PR is merged.